# How can I visualise a histogram of timestamps (stored in MySQL) without having to code much?

Tags: mysql, report

I have a big list of timestamps and I want to be able to plot them on graphs and display them in a similar way to google analytics, with the same easy ability to refresh the data and explore it interactively.

The timestamps are stored in a MySQL database, bonus points for a solution that automatically queries it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to answer without the slightest indication of what your data is or contains, but if you're counting clicks you're looking into a simple group by statement:

```
select date_format(click_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as click_date,
       count(*) as num_clicks
from clicks
where :start <= click_date and click_date < :end
group by date_format(click_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: That's actually a much cleaner solution than I had thought of, thanks a million!